# Get the data that is being loaded by jquery in PHP CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery, jquery-data

I have this dropdown menu using `form_helper` in CodeIgniter:

```
  <?php if($materialType): ?>

    <?php 
    $material_options = array();
    foreach($materialType as $rows){
        $material_options[$rows->id] = $rows->category; 
    }                                       
    echo form_dropdown('materialType',$material_options,'','id="materialType"');
    ?>

<?php endif; ?>

  <div id="materials"></div>
```

The code above is inside a `<form>` tag and I have this script:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var base_url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>"; 
  </script>

  <script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('change','#materialType',function(){
                loadthis();                 
            });

            function loadthis(){
                var ID  = $('#materialType').val();

                var dataString = 'id='+ ID ;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: base_url + "index.php/admin/get_material",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(data)
                    {
                    $('#materials').html(data);
                    }
                });     
            }

            loadthis();
        });

 </script>
```

And here is the code that is being loaded:

```
   <div id="materials">
   <?php if($materials): ?>
        <table>

            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <?php foreach($materials as $row): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row->mname; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->mdesc; ?></td>

                <td>
                    <button class="try" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>">Add</button>
                </td>

            </tr>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

    </table>

<?php else: ?>
    <div class="alert alert-error" style="width:300px;">No Resource Available!</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

```
   $(document).on('click','.try',function(){
            alert($(this).val());
            return false;
        });
```

And what i want is if the `Add` `button` is being click I can get the `ID`,`mname` and store it until the form is submitted.
How can I do that using `.data()` in jquery? or Any ideas on how to store it until the form is being submit.

Comment: where is this matId element ?

Comment: sorry for that. check it again i just edited

Comment: Because of the loop ..You have multiple elements with id=try ...to get the clicked one ..Try alert(this.val())

Comment: @LeonardDrapeza - `id` should be unique in DOM, if you need more `Add` button in the page, use `class` instead of `id`

Comment: i'd fixed that already but my problem is how can i store the data when until the form is being submitted?

Comment: @LeonardDrapeza Please make clear what you really want: `get the ID,mname` `id` of which element? `mname`? do you mean the first column content?

Comment: should i add a class on my table.td? `<td><?php echo $row->mname ?></td>` on that one?

Comment: @LeonardDrapeza please post a sample generated HTML DOM instead of the PHP code. and specify what you need in some paragraphs. I could help you then.

Comment: http://codejaw.com/2e3nfqg I dont know on how to work with DOM here mate. please undertand it. I think we should be working in .data() function in jquery.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35193/discussion-between-leonard-drapeza-and-hashem-qolami)

Comment: i cant join the room it says just a second but it takes a minute. do you have a facebook? let me add you mate

Answer (score 1):

I didn't thoroughly look at your code, but I noticed when you print your table rows in a loop you have the `id="try"` assigned to all of the rows. the html `id`-attribute is a unique identifier so the JS that is alerting the value will only return the value of the first id it will find (at least that's what i think). Try to use a `class` instread of an `id` and then use `this` in your js.

```
$(document).on('click','.try',function(){
    alert($(this).val());
    return false;
});
```

Comment: thanks. but how can i store it until the form is being submitted?

Comment: i'm not completely sure what you are trying to do. Just to sum it up. You have a couple of options that you want to mark before submitting the form. If that is what you want to achieve, then there are several options. **1)** you can submit everything in real-time via ajax to a basket. **2)** you can use checkboxes (or some other (hidden) input that carries a value when it was checked / selected) **3)** add some kind of `data-selected="true"` to your tag and then disable all other inputs that don't have this attribute... there are many options... it depends what you want to do...